# Shell substring with sed in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed, substring

I have tried this command in bash linux

```
echo "example=value" | sed "s/^example=\(.*\)$/\1/"
```

The output is `value`. But if I put it in a variable, it doesn't work.

For example:

```
var="example=value" | sed "s/^example=\(.*\)$/\1/"
echo $var
```

The output is nothing. What wrong?

Comment: `var=$(echo "example=value" | sed "s/^example=\(.*\)$/\1/")`

Comment: I'd tighten up your sed, and use strong quotes too: `var=$(echo "example=value"|sed 's/^.*=\(.*\)/\1/')`

Comment: Read the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson before attempting to write any more shell scripts as you are missing some crucial fundamentals and without learning the basics are about to embark on a career of writing very fragile shell scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var=$(echo example=value | sed "s/^example=\(.*\)$/\1/")
echo $var
```

Comment: To add, the `$()` tells bash to return the value as the right operand to the =.

Answer (score 1):

assigning a variable doesn't pass the value to `sed` via pipe.

You can pass while assigning like this:

`var="example=value" && echo "$var" |  sed "s/^example=\(.*\)$/\1/"`

or use a sub shell like this:

`var=$(echo "example=value" |  sed "s/^example=\(.*\)$/\1/")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without sed, using [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ var="example=value"
$ var="${var#*=}"
$ echo "$var"
value
```